# Powershell foreach loop to query AD for users from a .csv file

Tags: powershell, foreach

Total beginner with powershell trying to become more efficient in my helpdesk job. Essentially I have a .csv file with a list of e-mail addresses that I want to use to query AD to see what accounts are enabled/disabled. I don't get any output from what I've tried so far which is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$emails = Import-Csv -Path "c:\users\me\mycsvfile.csv"
foreach($email in $emails) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {userprincipalname -eq '$email.email'} | Select-Object name,enabled
}
```

The .csv file has a header for that column called email which is why I've used '$email.email'. Anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong (probably lots).

Many thanks

Comment: Start by picking a known good email and see if your `Get-ADUser` returns anything for the account. If not, there's something wrong with your filter, permissions or something else.

Comment: Can you make a small (sanitized) sample of your csv file?  More people will give you answers if you do that.

Comment: According to the docs of `Get-ADUser` (_"if curly braces are used to enclose the filter, the variable should not be quoted at all"_), your filter should be `{userprincipalname -eq $email.email}`

Answer (score 0):

These ad filters are a bit trial and error.

```
foreach($email in $emails) {
    $upn = $email.email
    Get-ADUser -Filter {userprincipalname -eq $upn} | Select-Object name,enabled
 }

name   enabled
----   -------
js     True
```

Answer (score 0):

A UserPrincipalName property **can** be the same as the users email address, but in fact they are different properties.
The similarity is that a UserPrincipalName (UPN) is the name of a system user in an **email address format**.

Let's assume in your domain the UPN is also the EmailAddress of a user.

I'm guessing your csv is really a text file with email addresses each on a separate line and that it has no header `email`.

Something like

```
you@yourdomain.com
him@yourdomain.com
her@yourdomain.com
someone.else@yourdomain.com
```

In that case, you either need to use `Get-Content` so you'll get all addresses (lines) as string array and loop over:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$emails = Get-Content -Path "c:\users\me\mycsvfile.csv"
foreach($email in $emails) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$email'" | Select-Object Name, Enabled
}
```

OR use `Import-Csv` and supply a header for the field(s) in there:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$emails = Import-Csv -Path "c:\users\me\mycsvfile.csv" -Header 'email'
foreach($email in $emails) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($email.email)'" | Select-Object Name, Enabled
}
```

- the `-Filter` parameter should actually be a **string** not a script block
- when using `object.property` syntax in a filter, you need to surround it with `$()`, making it a sub expression that gets parsed by PowerShell into the value it contains.